# Using selenium to fetch data

Tags: selenium, bots

I have a web application that I developed using Angular, Node.js/Express.js and MySQL. My app has some pages that display data after fetching it from another web app `example: https://www.example.com`. Since, this another app doesn't have any API from where I can fetch the data so, I am using web **scraping** with the help of Python Selenium and **scraping** the data from the site. I am calling my Python program in Node.js.

What I want to ask is that is the connection between a bot that sends a request to the target site secured or not? Does the selenium automated browser sends an encrypted connection to the site? Or, do I have to connect to a proxy to secure my connection. I don't want to expose my server's IP.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrapping. Scrapping means throwing away like rubbish.

Comment: @barny, sorry for my ignorance. I thought everything is with a double p in British English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not a **secure connection** cause Selenium internally makes an `HTTP request` for each **Selenium** command.

1. for each Selenium command, a HTTP request is created and sent to the browser driver
2. the browser driver uses a HTTP server for getting the HTTP requests
3. the HTTP server determines the steps needed for implementing the Selenium command
4. the implementation steps are executed on the browser
5. the execution status is sent back to the HTTP server
6. the HTTP server sends the status back to the automation script

[Why HTTP is not secure](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-in/learning/ssl/why-is-http-not-secure/)

[image]

Comment: Is it feasible to use an http proxy then? My main purpose is to hide my IP from the target site.

Comment: I don't know how much feasible it would be, but introducing proxy will definitely play a middleware role.

Answer (score 1):

selenium communication is between client library and driver API.
selenium doesn't send anything to the target site but the browser
If you are running selenium from local system and start selenium/driver in localhost there is no issue of "man in the middle attack" as no one can eavesdrop you as the communication is within the localhost netwrok.

Other than the communication between your script and the call to selenium API there is no other communication happening. All other communication is happening from the target website as in normal user scenarios.